# SQL join 3 tables and do sum

Tags: mysql

Iwould like to do a query on three tables:

the schema looks like this:

([take a look at the db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aLy2sEMfXFqyXtAV8gXho2/0))

tb1:
id, store_id, product_count

| id | store_id | product_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | store1 | 10 |
| def | store1 | 20 |
| ghi | store2 | 50 |

tb2:
id, product_id, product_type (A or B)

| id | product_id | product_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jkl | product1 | A |
| mno | product2 | A |
| pqr | product3 | B |
| stu | product4 | B |
| vwx | product5 | B |

tb3:
tb1_id, tb2_id

| tb1_id | tb2_id |
| --- | --- |
| abc | jkl |
| abc | mno |
| def | pqr |
| ghi | stu |
| ghi | vwx |

A store may have multiple products.

Now I would like to write a query and get a result like this:

| store_id | product_count_sum | product_type_A_count | product_type_B_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | 30 (10 + 20) | 2 | 1 |
| store2 | 50 | 0 | 2 |

I tried the following query, but the product_count_sum is not correct, and it seems like there's an issue when I try joining the 3 table (duplicate rows for a single store). Do anyone know how can I change this query and make it work as expected?

```
SELECT
    tb1.store_id AS store_id,
    sum(product_count) AS product_count_sum,
    sum(case when tb2.product_type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) AS product_type_A_count,
    sum(case when tb2.product_type = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) AS product_type_B_count
FROM tb1 AS tb1
JOIN tb3 AS tb3
ON tb1.id = tb3.tb1_id
JOIN tb2 AS tb2
ON tb3.tb2_id = tb2.id
GROUP BY tb1.store_id;
```

Comment: It seems like you're almost there, but if you're still struggling, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way:

```sql
SELECT
  tb1.store_id,
  SUM(tb1.product_count) AS total_product_count,
  t.product_type_A_count,
  t.product_type_B_count
FROM tb1
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      tb1.store_id AS store_id,
      SUM(CASE WHEN tb2.product_type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS product_type_A_count,
      SUM(CASE WHEN tb2.product_type = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS product_type_B_count
    FROM tb1
      JOIN tb3 ON tb1.id = tb3.tb1_id
      JOIN tb2 ON tb3.tb2_id = tb2.id
    GROUP BY store_id
  ) AS t ON tb1.store_id = t.store_id
GROUP BY tb1.store_id
;
```

(you can see the result in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba87ff/18/0))

The subquery will give you only the `store_id` and the total count of all the products of type A and B in each store. Then, the outside query will use directly the counts in the inner query and just sum the `product_count` on `tb1`. In this way you avoid that duplicates in `tb2` and `tb3` will invalidate the sum on `tb1.product_count`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this worked on mySQL, but we used postgreSQL and it's not working, error is: column "t.product_type_a_count" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Resolved the problem, your answer helped a lot. Thanks!